# Saving data with angular's $http

Tags: angularjs

I'm currently getting "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present" and a 404 not found when I try to do this. When I have the method as GET it works fine though. API is mocked using mockable.io. Is the header something I have to configure via mockable.io or am I just using angular wrong?

```
 var saveConfigs = function(){

  console.log("saving configurations...");

  $http({
    method: 'PUT',
    url: "http://demo9946042.mockable.io/lineGraphSample",
    data: $scope.theData,
    headers:{
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS',
    }
  })
  .success(function(){
      console.log("saving to server successful!");
   })
  .error(function(){
      console.log("failed to save");
  });

};
```

Comment: The Access-Control-Allow-Origin needs to be set on the server side. I'm not familiar with mockable.io though - you should add a tag for that instead.

Comment: Hmm..makes sense. Thanks for clearing that up. A tag for mockable.io doesn't exist though and I don't have the reputation to add it. I feel like it's really close though...is there something like mockable.io that allows me to GET and POST freely to a URL/JSON endpoint?

Comment: I would use [deployd](https://github.com/deployd/deployd) or [firebase](https://www.firebase.com/). Firebase has Angular bindings.

Comment: I actually checked out firebase but there was this weird error where keys couldn't have "." in the name. I have this file with keys like "jo.gp.nsfr" - -; Thanks for recommending deployd, I'll check it out!